# How can i get started with Google maps API, and can i make an interactive map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

let me start off by saying that i'm fairly new to web development and i'm taking on a bit of an advanced project as a bit of a learning experience. I'm looking to create a map quiz, with the help of Google Maps, of the worlds countries and their capitols. So i have a few question in relation to this.

- First off, is it even possible to make an interactive map(Like if it said click where the united states is and it would add a point )
- If it is, where can i get started researching on how to do this?
- What kind of language am i going to have to use to do this?

Comment: Check [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/). With JavaScript (Web part) you can do a lot very quickly.

Comment: @AntoJurković I checked it out, but there doesn't seem to be anything that would allow me to make a map quiz with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create the type of application you are looking for.  It is a matter of how much work you want to put into it.  In order to have users add markers to the map, this article on ["Events"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1) is helpful.  This should point you in the right direction for creating your quiz.

Regarding language, your quiz app can be done in Javascript as this is the language used for Google Maps API